# Why some words gives nonetype error in python?

Tags: python, nlp

I am using expand contraction in natural language processing. So I made function of Expand contraction.

```
from contractions import contractions_dict
def expand_contractions(text,contraction_mapping=contractions_dict):
    contractions_pattern=re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join
                                      (contraction_mapping.keys())),flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    def expand_match(contraction):
        match=contraction.group(0)
        first_char=match[0]
        expanded_contraction=contraction_mapping.get(match)\
            if contraction_mapping.get(match)\
            else contraction_mapping.get(match.lower())
        expanded_contraction=first_char+expanded_contraction[1:]
        return expanded_contraction                      
    expanded_text=contractions_pattern.sub(expand_match,str(text))
    expanded_text=re.sub("'"," ",expanded_text)
    return expanded_text
```

When I tried

```
expand_contractions("I'll be a son")
```

then it worked fine. But when i tried

```
expand_contractions("I'll be a daughter")
```

then it showed error i.e

> NoneType object is not subscriptable.

so I am not able to understand what is the problem with daughter word.
Please help me out.

Comment: Shouldn't the last 3 lines be indented inside `def expand_contractions`?

Comment: The error implies that `contraction_mapping.get(match.lower())` is returning `None`. What is the value of `match` when this happens, and does the lowercase version exist in the `contraction_mapping` dictionary?

Comment: @Barmar yes lower case version exist in the contraction_mapping

Comment: Make sure you have no space after the backslashes, it has to be right before the newline.

Comment: I have tried everything. As soon as the daughter word comes in a sentence it shows the error.

Comment: I ask again: What is the value of `match` when this happens?

Comment: The problem is with if the last word of the string is more than 4 characters used with *I'll* gives the error.

Comment: @Barmar value of a match is I'll which be replaced by I will by executing the contractions_pattern.sub command

Comment: No @DeepakK . if I use "I'll be a father" then it works fine.

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but why do you use `re.DOTALL`? The contractions shouldn't contain any `.` characters.

Comment: thanks @Barmar . I solved this problem by using pycontractions library. This library is giving me desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Something in contraction mapping is wrong.
Fixed it inserting try except.

```
def expand_contractions(text, contraction_mapping=contractions_dict):
  contractions_pattern = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(contraction_mapping.keys())),
                                    flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)

  def expand_match(contraction):
      match = contraction.group(0)
      first_char = match[0]
      expanded_contraction = contraction_mapping.get(match) \
          if contraction_mapping.get(match) \
          else contraction_mapping.get(match.lower())
      expanded_contraction = first_char + expanded_contraction[1:]
      return expanded_contraction


  try:
    expanded_text = contractions_pattern.sub(expand_match, text)
    expanded_text = re.sub("'", "", expanded_text)
  except:
    return text
  return expanded_text
```